# how to have many contracts in on service?

Tags: wcf, tcp

I have a service, that principal I would like to be duplex, however, for some operations, I need to use the streamed transfer mode, so I would like to have two contracts, one is the general contract, that let me interact with the database and send messages to the client from the service if I need it, and other contract  to interact with files, save and get the files to the database.

I need the two contracts because the tcp binding is not compatible with duplex.

The service is hosted in a WPF application, and the config files is the following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>          
      <service name="GTS.CMMS.Service.Service" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>

            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7997/CMMSHost"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7998/CMMSHost"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>   


        <endpoint address="/ServiceCore"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                  name="ServiceCore"
                  contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IService">
          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>


        <endpoint address="/ServiceDocumentos"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBindingDocumentos"
                  name="ServiceDocumentos"
                  contract="GTS.CMMS.Service.IServiceDocumentos">
          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>


        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexTcpBinding" address="net.tcp://localhost:5000/mex" />
      </service>      
    </services>


    <!--El behavior son datos de configuración del servicio que no forman parte del endpoint.
    Por ejemplo, si el servicio da una excepción, se querrá informar al cliente.-->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <!--Necesario para poder mandar excepciones desde el servicio hasta el cliente.-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
        </behavior>


        <behavior name="behaviorConfigDocumentos">
          <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <!--Necesario para poder mandar excepciones desde el servicio hasta el cliente.-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
          <serviceMetadata/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <!--Se necesita la configuración del binding para que funcione correctamente la comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor.-->
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <!--Se configura el binding que se utilizará para el endPoint ChatServiceAssembly.IChat-->
        <binding name="tcpBinding" maxBufferSize="67108864"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                       transferMode="Buffered" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                       openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
        </binding>


        <binding name="tcpBindingDocumentos" maxBufferSize="67108864"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                       transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                       openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                       sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

To check if all works, I go to the internet explorer and go to:

```
http://localhost:7998/CMMSHost
```

If I have the two endpoints, the page is not found, but if I comment the second endpoint, the "/ServiceDocumentos" the page is found and I can use svcutil to create the proxy.

How could I configure many endpoints?

Thanks.

Comment: in config shared you are using tcp for both binding, why you have address for http?

Comment: "I need the two contracts because the tcp binding is not compatible with duplex." Tcp binding is complitable with duplex.

Comment: Not if you want to use streaming transfer.